# Sorting subentities in a complex XML in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, xslt

I get some data from a WebService, which looks like this

```
Building
     Address
     -> Office
         Name
         CreationDate
         -> Worker
              Name
              HiringDate
```

Before doing further processing and transforms on this message, I need to sort the sub-nodes ("Office" and "Worker") so that all Offices are sorted by CreationDate, and then all Workers are sorted by HiringDate inside their Office.

So far the only solutions I've seen for sorting in BizTalk have been XSLT based. There are some samples that show how to sort on a simpler structure (http://www.biztalkgurus.com/newsletter/TheBizTalker-Volume-03.html) but those won't work as-is since my message has several levels.

If have no idea how to (if that is even possible) write an XSLT expression that will do this sorting while preserving the structure of the XML.

Is it possible to write such an XSLT expression? What would it look like?

Comment: Please, post a small xml document and the wanted XML result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here: 
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/wellink/archive/2005/12/09/10499.aspx

If we apply that technique to our example we get this XSLT

```
    <xsl:for-each select="Office">
        <xsl:sort select="CreationDate" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>        
        <Office>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="CreationDate"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Worker">
                <xsl:sort select="HiringDate" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                <Worker>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="HiringDate"/>
                </Worker>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Office>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Then hook it up in the Map as shown below and it works fine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a XSLT copy templates for all tags exclude Office and Worker, and sorting templates for that tags. eg
Copy templates:

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:if test="name()">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And sorting templates:

```
<xsl:match="office_parent_tag_as_i_understand_Building">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Office">
        <xsl:sort select="CreationDate" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:foreach>
</xsl:template>
```

& analog for Worker tag

```
<xsl:match="worker_parent_tag_as_i_understand_Office">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Worker">
        <xsl:sort select="HiringDate" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:foreach>
</xsl:template>
```

Don't forget that xsl:sort works only with numeric and text data, for sorting by date you need to convert date to int or string

Comment: I'm not sure how you would enter all that XSLT inside biztalk (it has only 1 script window for inline XSLT and doesn't accept a template object inside it it seems). And how you you connect the output to the right side schema in that case?